# JavaFX 8 files drag and drop works but copy and paste doesn't

Tags: java, linux

I am writing JavaFX 8 application.
I can successfully drag one or more files from my application and drop them into a file manager (Naitilus).
Here is how I put the files to the dragboard:

```
    private void dragDetected(MouseEvent mouseEvent,Thumbnail thumbnail) {
        Dragboard dragboard = thumbnail.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);
        ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
        List<File> lstFileSelected = getListFileSelected();
        clipboardContent.putFiles(lstFileSelected);
        dragboard.setContent(clipboardContent);

        mouseEvent.consume();
    }
```

I can successfully copy a string from my application and paste it in an outer editor (gEdit).
Here is how I put the string to the system clipboard:

```
    private void copyToClipboard() {
        Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
        clipboardContent.putString("Dummy");
        clipboard.setContent(clipboardContent);
    }
```

But when I try to copy one or more files from my application and to paste them into a file manger (Nautilus), into a folder with permissions==0777, I can't do this as a 'paste' option in the file manager's menu is disabled.
Here is how i put the files to the system clipboard:

```
    private void copyToClipboard() {
        Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
        List<File> lstFileSelected = getListFileSelected();
        // lstFileSelected DOES HAVE all the selected files (one or more)
        clipboardContent.putFiles(lstFileSelected);
        clipboard.setContent(clipboardContent);
    }
```

My environment:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) 64-bit with Gnome 3.22.2
Java jdk-8u152-linux-x64
Eclipse SDK Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a)
```

Can anybody help me to understand what is wrong.
Thank you, Mikhail.